# How to style an inline form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a simple label and select box for a form.

I want this: `[LABEL] [SELECT BOX]`. Inline. All on the same line. Simple, eh?

Yet when I use the inline form element from bootstrap, it wraps the box:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <label for="sort-values">Sort:
        <select id="sort-values" class="form-control">
            <option value="2">Distance</option>
            <option value="3">Rating</option>
            <option value="4">Price</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</form>
```

What am I missing? Example here: http://bootply.com/79458

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of the element `.form-control` is the problem..

```
.form-control {
    width: 100%;
}
```

It is currently at 100%.. if you want it to work, you can either remove the width completely.. or just specify a smaller width, such as 200px;

[**Forked example here**](http://bootply.com/79462)

Comment: Almost - it's not the width of the form, it's the width of the element that has the `.form-control` class (select box)

Comment: Thanks, interesting - I would have thought that the form-inline class should fix this, else it's... well... not inline!; is it an oversight in BS3?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two methods for linking `label` and `select`. First method: `id` for `select` and attribute `for` for label. Second: including `select` inside of `label`. Not necessary use both of them.

Code:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <label class="control-label" for="sort-values">Sort:</label>
    <select id="sort-values" class="form-control">
        <option value="2">Distance</option>
        <option value="3">Rating</option>
        <option value="4">Price</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Example: http://bootply.com/79462

Comment: Sorry, I missing `class="form-control"` for `select`. Forked variant: http://bootply.com/79462 (I updated my answer.)

Comment: I'm not a bootstrap-using dev but, just looking at the docs, this appears to be the correct way to do it. +1